# How to differentiate the use of reference from addressing as for "&"

Tags: c++

Sometimes it can be bit confusing to me. Is there easy way to tell each time the mark & is used as a reference or getting address.

Comment: `int& x` is a reference to an `int`. `int x; &x;` is taking the address of the `int` variable `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Reference & is used in declarations while operator & is used in expressions.:)

Consider example

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int * const &r = &x;

    std::cout << "x  = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*r = " << *r << std::endl;

}
```

The output is

```
x  = 10
*r = 10
```

In statement

```
    int * const &r = &x;
```

in its left part there is declaration of reference `&r` and in the right part there is initialization expression `&x`

Comment: This is the simplest way to view it. Of course, there are two different operators denoted by &, though...

Comment: Except for `static_cast<T&>()` of course ;)

Comment: What about `int* x = &y;`? :P

Comment: @Luchian Grigore  Here &y is an expression.

Comment: and int* x = &y; is declaration.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore  Here is declared only identifier x. It can be declared without an initializer expression. See the C++ grammar about what is declaration.

Comment: "Here is declared only identifier x. It can be declared without an initializer expression." never said it can't be. I don't have access to the standard right now, can you just tell me whether `int* x = &y;` is a declaration?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore  Declaration introduces a name in a translation unit. So in line you showed only x is declared. As for y then it and correspondingly operator & are used in expression. They declare nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If it's part of a type specification (in a declaration, template argument, or somewhere else where a type is expected), it means the type is a reference.

```
int& x;                          // `x` has reference type `int&`
some_template<int&> t;           // template specialised for reference type `int&`
reinterpret_cast<char&>(x) = 42; // cast to reference type
```

If it's part of an expression (where a type isn't expected), used as a unary operator, it takes the address of the following operand.

```
int n;
int* x = &n;  // initialiser expression takes the address of `n`
```

If it's part of an expression, used as a binary operator, it means the bitwise "and" of the two surrounding operands.

```
int a = 0x123, b = 0xf;
int x = a & b;    // bitwise "and" gives x = 0x3
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `&` when you declare a reference. So this happens in two places:

1. Function parameter definitions
2. Declaring variables on the lhs

Everywhere else (ie on the rhs) unary `&` acts as an operator meaning 'address of' (binary `&` otherwise means bitwise AND)